# Representation of diagonal operator in $l^2$ as a multiplication operator in $L_2(X,\mu)$ (spectral theorem)

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

There is a (weaker) version of spectral theorem saying that any self-adjoint operator in Hilbert space is unitarily isomorphic to multiplication operator in $L_2(X,\mu)$, where $(X,\mu)$ is some measurable space.

How can we find such a representation, for example, for a diagonal operator? I mean, how to choose $X,\mu,$ the function $f$ for multiplication operator and the unitary isomorphism needed for unitary equivalence?

Thank you.

Comment: A "diagonal" operator _is_ a multiplication operator!

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich What did you imply by isometry $f\mapsto f$? I mean, it should be from $L_2(\mathbb{N},\mu)$ to $l^2$. Sorry, if question is dumb

Comment: You didn't specify whether you were talking about $\ell_2(\Bbb N)$ or some other $\ell_2$. In fact $\ell_2(\Bbb N)=L^2(\Bbb N, \mu)$ if $\mu$ is counting measure. The identity is a unitary isomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it a "diagonal operator" is $T:\ell_2\to\ell_2$ given by $$T(x_1,x_2,\dots)=(m_1x_1,m_2,m_2,\dots)$$for some sequence $m_j$. This means that a diagonal operator *is* a multiplication operator! Let $X=\Bbb N$, let $\mu$ be counting measure on $\Bbb N$ and define $U:\ell_2\to L^2(X,\mu)$ by $$Ux=x.$$Then $Tx=U^{-1}mUx$.